# Python AST not using imported modules

Tags: python, python-import, abstract-syntax-tree

I've been working with Python's AST (abstract syntax tree) module recently and came upon an issue with it not seeming to run import statements. I couldn't find anything about this and I'm not exactly sure what's going on.

## Explanation

When parsing a .py file with AST, and then compiling/running the tree, import statements in the tree are seemingly ignored in favor of those in the script doing the parsing.

## Example

Here is a minimal working example of the issue. Made from the [extended AST documentation](https://greentreesnakes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tofrom.html)

**test.py**

```
from random import choice

def ast_broken_demo():
    lis = ["foo", "bar"]
    print(choice(lis))

ast_broken_demo()
```

**parser.py**

```
import ast
#from random import choice

def main():
    path = "test.py"
    source_code = open(path).read()

    a = ast.parse(source_code)
    ast.fix_missing_locations(a)
    co = compile(a, '<ast>', 'exec')
    print(ast.dump(a))
    exec(co)

main()
```

This results in an error message:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last): 
 File "test.py", line 18, in <module>
   main()   
 File "test.py", line 16, in main
   exec(co)   
 File "<ast>", line 19, in <module>   
 File "<ast>", line 17, in ast_broken_demo 
 NameError: name 'choice' is not defined
```

This resolves if you put `from random import choice` at the top of **parser.py**, but I shouldn't have to, because that exact line is in **test.py** and should be executed when the AST runs. Putting the import in **parser.py** is especially bad because the parser is supposed to parse any arbitrary .py file, so I can't possibly import everything anyone could possibly use.

Whats going on here? Why is the parsing using the wrong imports or not running the import statements inside of **test.py**? Thank you.

Comment: Assigning variables (including with `def` or `import`) using `exec` with the default locals is undefined behavior.

Comment: @user2357112 so then the solution is to pass in a scope to exec? Which one? {}, globals(), and locals() all solve the issue. But I'm not sure which is correct, this is new territory for me

Comment: Not locals(), because modifying locals() is undefined behavior. Aside from that, use whatever scope you want to execute the code in.

Comment: @user2357112 Sounds good. If I have this right, I chose simply create an empty namespace `new_namespace = {}` and pass that as the second argument to exec. Exec automatically fills it with the __builtins__, and uses it as the global (or module?) scope for whatever it executes. New local namespaces are created and popped as normal, and at the end, new_namespace contains only the global level variables and function/class references. In my testing so far this doesn't seem to cause any weird scoping issues, so hopefully it stays that way and I actually understand what's going on.